# Trouble finding intersection of Line and irregular RegionBoundary

Tags: regions

I am having trouble finding the intersection of an infinite line and an irregular `RegionBoundary`.  *Mathematica* cannot return `DiscretizeRegion`.

Any suggestions?

[image: Irregular Polygon with infinite line]

[image: Irregular Polygon]

```
perimeterOfArea = 
   RegionBoundary[Polygon[perimeterPoints[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]];

regionTwo = RegionIntersection[
   perimeterOfArea, 
   InfiniteLine[{894400, 2.7675*10^6}, {1, 0}]
];

DiscretizeRegion[regionTwo]

DiscretizeRegion::drf: DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize 
the region RegionIntersection.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for illustrative purposes:

```
m = DelaunayMesh[RandomReal[1, {15, 2}]];
b = RegionBoundary[m];
f[p1_, p2_] := 
 Module[{line = InfiniteLine[{p1, p2}], mp = MeshPrimitives[b, 1], ri},
  ri = (RegionIntersection[line, #] & /@ mp) /. 
    EmptyRegion[_] :> Sequence[]; 
  If[Length@ri > 0, ri, {}]]
Manipulate[
 Module[{i = f[p, q]},
  Show[
   Graphics[{InfiniteLine[{p, q}], Red, PointSize[0.02], i}, 
    PlotRange -> Table[{0, 1.25}, 2], 
    PlotLabel -> (i /. Point[x_] :> {x})], b]],
 {{p, {0.1, 0.1}}, Locator}, {{q, {0.4, 0.4}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating the `RegionBoundary` of a `Polygon`, you could consider constructing a `Line` from your set of points.

For instance:

```
points = CirclePoints[8];
line = Line@ Join[points, points[[{1}]]];
il = InfiniteLine[{{0.5, 0.5}, {1.5, 0.5}}];

RegionIntersection[line, il]
(* Point[{{-0.806563, 0.5}, {0.806563, 0.5}}] *)
```

In this simple example, taking the region boundary of the polygon is equivalent to generating the line from its points:

```
line === RegionBoundary[Polygon@ points]
(* True *)
```

Although in your case it is not (an expression with head `MeshRegion` rather than `Line` is output from `RegionBoundary`), this alternative may work for your data.